# SQL not finding a result when using WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here's my SQL:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE to = '0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,30");
```

And my table looks like this:

[image: z]

Why does it not find it? If I remove the `WHERE to = '0'` it works fine.

Comment: `WHERE TRIM(to) = '0'` Whitespaces probably

Comment: Always consult the manual before writing MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html

Comment: Is your to `string`? or `int`?

Comment: @aldrin27 It's a string.

Comment: comments #1 and #3, won't do a difference. It's #2 OP needs to worry about.

Comment: Yeah, it worked, thanks @Fred-ii-!